# How do I access a dynamically loaded label from a method that didn't create it using Cocoa-Touch?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I need to set the text of a label from a method that didn't create it.

The label is created on viewdidload and the method that needs to change the label is not in viewdidload.

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create that UILabel as property as:

in YourClass.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *myLabel;
```

Synthesize it in YourClass.m

```
@synthesize myLabel;
```

now when you create this label in viewDidLoad method do it like this

```
self.myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init] autorelease];
//set the frame, color and text properties here
self.myLabel.text = @"initial text";
self.myLabel.frame =  CGRectMake(0,0,30,100);
```

And whenever you need to access the UILabel to update any of it's properties like text you can do it by using the self accessor as:

```
self.myLabel.text = @"Updated text here";
```

When you do this make sure you set myLabel to nil in viewDidUnload to handle memory properly.

Comment: Oh i get it now, except when i try to set it to nil on viewdidunload it gives me an error for "no visible @interface for 'myclass' declares the selector 'mylabel'"

Answer (score 0):

make the uilabel as the instance variable of the class. initialize it in viewdidload and set the text in whichever method you want.

EDIT:
Check this code example:
In header:

```
UILabel *myLabel;
```

In implementation:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {
     myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:myFrame]];
     [self.view addSubview:mylabel]
 }
 -(void)sumOtherMethod {
     myLabel.text = @"this is my text";
 }
```

Comment: declare UILabel in the header of the viewController. And use that in code. I am editing the answer. Check it out.

Comment: I tried that, it gives me a bunch of errors on the code that creates it.. remember it is a programmatically created label.